# std::shared_ptr initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

What is the difference between:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> p1 = std::shared_ptr<int>(new int);
```

and

```
std::shared_ptr<int> p2 = (std::shared_ptr<int>) new int;
```

Which is better and why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Neither. This one is strictly preferable:

```
auto p3 = std::make_shared<int>();
```

(Although it has slightly different semantics, since it initializes the `int` object, unlike your code.)

This version is subexpression-wise correct, doesn't contain the red-flag word "new", and also uses a more efficient allocation scheme.